# How do I find out when a resize ends in a Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

In an ordinary WinForms application we have an event called `ResizeEnd`, but in a Silverlight I can't find it.

There must be a way for knowing when user releases the left mouse button after resizing the browser window, so that I can handle just one resize (or `SizeChanged`) event (the last one) instead of every occurrence of this event.

Comment: @MartinLiversage - that would be my fault in the edit (I've corrected it)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`OnResize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838211%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event.

> Specifies a handler for the **Resized** event that occurs when the Silverlight plug-in's **object** tag is resized and the ActualHeight or the ActualWidth of the Silverlight plug-in change.

This is specified in the HTML/ASP:

```
<object ...>
    ...
    <param name "onresize" value"functionname" />
    ...
</object>
```

This is fired when the `ActualHeight` or `ActualWidth` properties change - but not when the Silverlight plugin is in full screen mode.

Unfortunately I can't find any information to indicate how many times this would be fired while the browser window is changing size.

Comment: thanx Chris, but SizeChanged is called with no problem. what i need to know is exactly the last one. OnResize may be handled, but can't help.